# How to set 2 GPUs on Ubuntu?

Tags: xorg

I have 4 monitors and 2 GPUs.
I have tried to set 2 monitors for each one of GPU.
So, I could have 2 sets of this 
(each set is prefered as 2 monitors connected to 1 GPUs)...

Here is my problem.
It seems Ubuntu(xconf.org) does not allow me to set 2 GPUs.
Either one of GPU is working(in result, I only get to have 2 monitors working)

Can anyone tell me how to set 2 GPUs on Ubuntu?

```
                                         thank you in advance..
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use two video cards to power three screens?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/120784/how-can-i-use-two-video-cards-to-power-three-screens)